# Sampling on two columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I work for a company that carries out repairs on properties. Each repair has a unique number, as does each property (around 15000 records) and each workman (there are roughly 30). Every month we make somewhere between 2000 and 4000 repairs.

In order for the company to carry out satisfaction surveys we need to randomly (preferably, but could just use TOP) select 5 properties per workman per month, while ensuring that the property has not previously been sent a survey within the previous 3 months (this will be an attribute).

Essentially I'm  looking for a tip to do the following:

`+-------+---------+-------+-----------------+
| Place |  Worker | Date  | previous survey |
+-------+---------+-------+-----------------+
|  0001 |       1 | june1 |                 |
|  0002 |       1 | june1 |                 |
|  0003 |       2 | june1 |                 |
|  0004 |       1 | june1 | Y               |
|  0005 |       2 | june1 |                 |
|  0006 |       2 | june1 |                 |
|  0007 |       1 | june1 |                 |
|  0008 |       1 | june1 |                 |
|  0009 |       1 | june1 |                 |
|  0010 |       2 | june1 |                 |
|  0011 |       1 | june1 |                 |
|  0012 |       2 | june1 |                 |
|  0013 |       1 | june1 |                 |
|  0014 |       1 | june1 | Y               |
|  0015 |       1 | june1 |                 |
+-------+---------+-------+-----------------+`

Outputting:

`Worker | Place
  1     |0001
  1     |0002
  1     |0007
  1     |0008
  1     |0009
  2     |0003
  2     |0005
  2     |0006
  2     |0012
  2     |NULL`

.... and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I don't even know what to google to begin sorting this out!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.For starters, are you using mysql or sql server? They are not the same thing and the answer will be very different depending on which DBMS you are actually using.

Comment: MySQL doenst support TOP (you are talking about using TOP) so why is MySQL tagged?

Comment: Sorry! Mis-tagging (first post) mysql shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT worker_id, place 
FROM <yourtable> 
WHERE previous_survey != 'Y' 
ORDER BY place ASC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily leverage ROW_NUMBER for this kind of thing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql

```
with SortedResults as
(
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Worker order by (Select newid())) as RowNum
    from YourTable
    where PreviousSurvey is null --or whatever the predicate would be here
)

select *
from SortedResults
where RowNum <= 5
```

Comment: This is perfect, and so simple. Will there be any problems with this if the table is larger?

Comment: Given the probable distribution of data it should scale reasonably well. Of course if you have millions of rows it could be a challenge but then so could all the other queries.